# Can't get more than 12 results when using Woocommerce REST API with JWT Authentication for WP-API

Tags: wordpress, react-native, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I'm developing a React Native app and hooking it to a WP Woocommerce backend.

When I used to request data through OAuth 1.0, everything was working fine, but since I changed to JWT Authentication with the plugin "JWT Authentication for WP-API", I only get maximum 12 results when I request all products to be listed.

The request I'm doing is with bearer token and the url is /wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100

However, I get a response on the header of "X-WP-Total  12" max

Any idea how can I solve this so I get all proudcts??

Comment: Maybe the plugin sets a limit within the query. You should check it.

Comment: I tried looking for files in the plugin but couldn't find any filters in the query... not sure if I'm looking in the right place...

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved it thanks to this post https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fix-basic-authentication-jwt_auth_bad_auth_header-error/

I had to open the file:

wp-content/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/public/class-jwt-auth-public.php

On line 250 where it says

```
    /*
     * The HTTP_AUTHORIZATION is present verify the format
     * if the format is wrong return the user.
     */
    list($token) = sscanf($auth, 'Bearer %s');
    if (!$token) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'jwt_auth_bad_auth_header',
            'Authorization header malformed.',
            array(
                'status' => 403,
            )
        );
    }
```

replace these lines with

```
if (!$token) {
        // Get token using basic auth
        list($username, $password) = explode( ':', base64_decode( substr( $auth, 6 ) ) );
        $request = new WP_REST_Request( 'POST', '/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token' );
        $request->set_param( 'username', $username );
        $request->set_param( 'password', $password );
        $JWT = new Jwt_Auth_Public('jwt-auth', '1.1.0');
        $token = $JWT->generate_token( $request );
        if (is_array($token) && isset($token['token'])) $token = $token['token'];
        return;
    }
```

after doing this when we add the suffix ?per_page=100 to the GET request, then it works properly.